# Lower semi-continuous function which is unbounded on compact set.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Every lower semi-continuous functions attains an infimum/minimum on a compact set, do you know examples of lower semi-continuous functions which are unbounded and/or don't attain their maximum/supremum?

Comment: Um, if the function is unbounded it can't attain it's supremum unless you allow the function to take the value infinity. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: maybe in the first line you mean infimum/minimum instead of infimum/maximum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
 f(x)=\begin{cases}1/x&x\in(0,1],\\0&x=0.\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}\frac1x&\text{when }x>0\\[6pt]0&\text{when }x\le0\end{array}\right.
$$
on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

On the interval $[0,1]$, let
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases} 0&\mbox{ if } t=0\\ \\\ \frac1t&\mbox{ if }t>0\end{cases}
$$